# SQLAlchemy - MappedCollection problem

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have some problems with setting up the dictionary collection in Python's SQLAlchemy:

I am using declarative definition of tables. I have `Item` table in 1:N relation with `Record` table. I set up the relation using the following code:

```
_Base = declarative_base()

class Record(_Base):
    __tablename__ = 'records'

    item_id = Column(String(M_ITEM_ID), ForeignKey('items.id'))
    id = Column(String(M_RECORD_ID), primary_key=True)
    uri = Column(String(M_RECORD_URI))
    name = Column(String(M_RECORD_NAME))

class Item(_Base):
    __tablename__ = 'items'

    id = Column(String(M_ITEM_ID), primary_key=True)

    records = relation(Record, collection_class=column_mapped_collection(Record.name), backref='item')
```

Now I want to work with the `Item`s and `Record`s. Let's create some objects:

```
i1 = Item(id='id1')
r = Record(id='mujrecord')
```

And now I want to associate these objects using the following code:

```
i1.records['source_wav'] = r
```

but the `Record r` doesn't have set the `name` attribute (the foreign key). Is there any solution how to automatically ensure this? (I know that setting the foreign key during the `Record` creation works, but it doesn't sound good for me).

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You want something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import validates

class Item(_Base):
    [...]

    @validates('records')
    def validate_record(self, key, record):
      assert record.name is not None, "Record fails validation, must have a name"
      return record
```

With this, you get the desired validation:

```
>>> i1 = Item(id='id1')
>>> r = Record(id='mujrecord')
>>> i1.records['source_wav'] = r
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
AssertionError: Record fails validation, must have a name
>>> r.name = 'foo'
>>> i1.records['source_wav'] = r
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet, so I'm just going to write this as a separate answer:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import validates

class Item(_Base):
    [...]

    @validates('records')
    def validate_record(self, key, record):
      record.name=key
      return record
```

This is basically a copy of Gunnlaugur's answer but abusing the validates decorator to do something more useful than exploding.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
backref='item'
```

Is this a typo for

```
backref='name'
```

?

Comment: Probably not. The backref is the name of an attribute that sqlalchemy will add to the other side of the relation (the Record class), to refer back to the object (Item instance) holding the forward reference. So 'item' makes sense -- in honzas' example, r.item yields the Item instance.